# Can't get scrollview to work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview

my code of the XML file I am currently working in! So what I want is to make it possible to scroll in this screen, however there are currently no objects that fall outside of the screen but they will in the future. Hope This gives enough info for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#666666">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name:  "
        android:id="@+id/NameView" />

        <TextView

        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:text="@string/nameString"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Adress:"
            android:id="@+id/AdresView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/adressString"
            android:id="@+id/Adress"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />>

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="E-mail:"
        android:id="@+id/emailView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/emailString"
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Mobile:"
        android:id="@+id/mobileView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/mobileString"
            android:id="@+id/Mobile"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.75" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit Profile"
        android:id="@+id/BeditProfile"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="240dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
        </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Uhhh, use a ScrollView?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I intentionally left the scrollview out. because I didn't get the result that I wanted, it didn't scroll when i implemented it, and since I have multiple layouts, (one for each data segment) I am making a profile I want it all to scroll, meaning the entire page

Comment: What Grabriella said... or your just not explaining yourself properly.

Comment: check my answer may be it solve your problem

Comment: The `ScrollView` must only have one child. You need to add a `LinerLayout` inside the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ScrollView` instead of `LinearLayout` then i will be work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#666666"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <!-- Your all XML code paste here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this and the emulator responded by saying android studio has stopped working

Comment: because it depend upon you screen size your emulator screen size greater then your whole layout. if add more view e.g button edittext.... automatically scrollview become enable

Comment: TY, I got it to work, it think. At least no errors that I know off or anything else like that. Hopefully when I actually have to use it, that it will work. Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a screen scrollable just use a `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The ScrollView must only have one direct child!

Answer (score 1):

Put everything in one `ScrollView` and you will be able to scroll everything - so the main `LinearLayout` should be wrapped in a `ScrollView`